# How can I see a page-table maintained by each process in Virtual Memory - Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel, virtualization

In the virtual memory concept- each process maintains their own page table. This page table maps the virtual address to the kernel virtual address. This kernel virtual address translates the address to Physical RAM. I understand that there is a Kernel Virtual adddres - vm area struct. This vm area struct finally maps this address to the Physical address.
When I do cat /proc//maps - I see the direct mapping of virtual address to physical address. Because it maps the address to the file - with inode. So, it looks that it is the address on the hard-disk, file descriptor, major-minor number. There are a few address that are on the RAM. So, I can say that I can't see the table where the Virtual address is mapped to Kernel virtual address. I want to see that table. How can I see that? It should not be in the kernel space. Because when process is accessing let's say memory - 0x1681010 then this should be translated to kernel virtual memory address. Finally, this address should be translated to physical memory address.

Comment: The physical address has no meaning in userspace. It could change every single time you ask for it, or not exist at all. The maps in `/proc/maps` only tell you the regions of virtual address space that your process has been given.

Comment: There's no translation from virtual address to "kernel virtual memory" when accessing memory- that's why you don't see that translation, it doesn't exist. There's only virtual memory to physical memory translation going on.

Comment: Ok, I have referred this link - http://users.nccs.gov/~fwang2/linux/lk_addressing.txt  . The excerpt from this link is "In order to access *any* physical pages, that page *must* be in the process's
page table - every process has its own page table. That is the base." ----This means that every process maintains its pagetable. How a virtual memory can be translated to Physical address. Definitely it needs a page table for it. How it can access that page table? Where this page table resides? User space cannot access kernel space- remember. This means pagetable should be in user space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the [Linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) maintains the processes page tables (but not the processes themselves). [Processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) are only seeing [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) thorough their [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space). Processes use some [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall), like e.g. [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) or [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), to change their address space.

Physical addresses and page tables and dealing with and managing the [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) is the business of the kernel, which actually provides some "[abstract machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_machine)" (with the virtual address spaces, the syscalls as atomic elementary operations, etc...) to user applications. The applications don't see the raw (x86) hardware, but only the [user mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_mode) as given by the kernel. Some hardware resources and instructions are not available to them (they only run in [user space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes)).

<sup>The page tables are managed by the kernel, and indeed various processes may use different -or sometimes same- page tables. (So [context switches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) managed by the kernl may need to reconfigure the MMU). You don't care, (and the user processes don't see page tables) the kernel will manage them.</sup>

And no, `/proc/self/maps` does not show anything about physical addresses, only about virtual one. The kernel is permitted to move processes from one core to another, to move pages from one physical (not virtual) address to another, etc...., at any time; and applications usually don't see this (they might query this with [mincore(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mincore.2.html), [getcpu(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcpu.2.html) and thru [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) ...)

Applications should not care about *physical* memory or [interrupts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt), like [page faults](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault) (only the kernel care about these; sometimes by sending signals).

<sup>The virtual to physical address translation happens in the MMU. Usually, it is successful (perhaps transparently accessing page tables), and the processor sends on the bus to the RAM the translated physical address (corresponding to some virtual address handled by the user-mode machine instruction). When the MMU cannot handle it, a page fault occurs, which is processed by the kernel (which could swap-in some page, send a `SIGSEGV`, do a context switch, etc...)</sup>

See also the [processor architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_architecture), [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set), [page table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table), [paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging), [translation lookaside buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer), [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29), [x86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) and [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) wikipages (and follow all the links I gave you).

Comment: I have added a comments at the top. I am not happy with the answer. I have referred a link. If page table is in the kernel space then how a process-running on kernel space can access the page table? Let's say char * a; memcpy(a,13,1); . What is the address of a. If we print, we get the virtual address. But actually while copying on address a, it would have got the physical address on RAM. So, it needs a page table to translate that address to physical one. It can't access kernel space- remember user cannot access directly a kernel space. It needs system call.

Comment: A process does not access to kernel space. Only the kernel works in kernel space. User processes interact with kernel only thru syscalls. A user process don't see physical addresses so don't care about them.

Comment: Adding further to it, I don't think so that for every memory access there will be a system call from user space in order to translate the address.

Comment: No, that is handled by the MMU. The kernel handles page faults. Most accesses go directly (via the MMU) to memory, but they are using virtual addresses (which the MMU has successfully translated to some physical address).

Comment: At Basile, If you say like that, which I agree then how a process memory address is translated to a physical address? Just think from a process perspective. A process is trying to access a virtual address say  0x1681010. This should be translated to a physical address. how that translation will happen, Where is the map table- page table? If it is in kernel then it needs to call system calls. If not then I should be able to see the page table via user space.

Comment: Thanks! So, The kernel also maintains the similar map in vmarea. In terms, where the process data resides - in main memory , storage.So, if a page fault happens then the kernel will check in the vmarea data structure to load that page in the phyiscal page. Now MMU will succeed in translating. Am I correct? If I am correct hen what I see in /proc/<pid>/map is the kernel vmarea right? This has a complete information on where the part of process resides in main memory as well as Hard-disk. The MMU knows only RAM. If it fails then pagefault and kernel will take the help of vmarea stru to resolve.

Comment: What you see in `/proc/self/maps` is only about virtual addresses as managed by the kernel.

Comment: Please take time to read and follow all the links I gave you.

Comment: Ok, Last doubt - 7feb587bd000-7feb587cb000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 789721                     /usr/lib64/GConf/2/libgconfbackend-xml.so
7feb587cb000-7feb589ca000 ---p 0000e000 fd:01 789721                     /usr/lib64/GConf/2/libgconfbackend-xml.so This means that teh address 7feb587cb000-7feb589ca000 is actually mapped to the file descriptor 01, and the device identity is 789721. 
7feb589ca000-7feb589cb000 r--p 0000d000 fd:01 789721                     /usr/lib64/GConf/2/libgconfbackend-xml.so

Comment: Ok, I will but can you acknowledge that what I have written is right or wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41357/discussion-between-shreyas-joshi-and-basile-starynkevitch)